# how do you increment a field in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Say, you got a table of 100 records. And field `age` contains a some integers. And you want all those integers to be incremented by 1.

or you got a textfield called `name` and a bunch of names in there. And you want all those names to be prefixed as `Mr.`.

Is there a way to achieve this in one SQL command?

The alternative would be to compile a recordset of these 100 recs and going thru a loop and then running an individual update statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `UPDATE mytable SET age = age+1`
2. `UPDATE mytable SET name = CONCAT('Mr. ', name`)

If MySQL is in [ANSI mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) – specifically, [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat), you can use `'Mr. ' || name` instead.

Comment: Hi Matt, Is the | symbol an equal alternative to the + symbol in Dan J's reply?

Comment: For string concatenation, or for addition? AFAIK the two are _never_ interchangeable in SQL.

Comment: that opens up all kinds of potentials for me. I guess I can use other SQL functions there such as `replace` - I mean in place of the `concat` that is. Right?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) command

```
update yourtable
set age=age +1 

update yourtable
set name = 'Mr. ' + name
where gender='M'
```